# Looking for HDR raw data or high frame rate data, preferrably from satelites

Tags: geospatial

I'm working on an algorithm to enhance camera resolution.  Ideally the scene is static between the frames, and I need minimally the raw files that go into HDR images, or high frame rate data (the higher the better).

Answer (score 2):

This is a non-answer, but I think you should take your own photos. Then you can create a testable data set with varying lighting conditions.

And then release it to the public!

---

That being said, here's a dataset with 5GB of RAW photos

http://mmlab.science.unitn.it/RAISE/

> RAISE is a challenging real-world image dataset, primarily designed for the evaluation of digital forgery detection algorithms. It consists of 8156 high-resolution RAW images, uncompressed and guaranteed to be camera-native (i.e., never touched or processed). All the images have been collected from 4 photographers over a period of 3 years (2011- 2014), capturing different scenes and moments in over 80 places in Europe employing 3 different cameras.

Comment: Thanks.  I've been using Google's recent HDR+ dataset (http://www.hdrplusdata.org/).  It would be nice to have longer distance images, or non-hdr high frame rate data.  The latter could be application agnostic.